Error when using lottie-react within custom package
Background:
I created a custom TextDisplay react typescript component which adds an eclipse to the text based on the maxWidth. In addition the component has a copy button next to the text when the user's mouse is over the text so that the full text can be copied to his clipboard. After the user has copied the text I show a lottie animation for 2.5 seconds. I used the lottie-react package for this.
The Issue:
When I have the component code directly in my Next JS typescript project this component works like a charm. When I extract it to a github package that I have I start running into issues. The TextDisplay component itself works overall and is rendered in my next project which uses the package. When I press copy though (when the lottie animation tries rendering), the app crashes with the folowing message:

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `ClipboardCopy`.
    at ClipboardCopy (webpack-internal:///../internal-packages/components/core/dist/esm/TextDisplay/TextDisplay.js:285:19)
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../internal-packages/components/core/node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/Box/Box.js:45:18)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///../internal-packages/components/core/node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/Text/Text.js:50:87)
    at TextDisplay (webpack-internal:///../internal-packages/components/core/dist/esm/TextDisplay/TextDisplay.js:220:15)
    at td
    at TextCell (webpack-internal:///./Components/shared/DataTable/TextCell.tsx:27:23)
    at tr
    at TableRow (webpack-internal:///./Components/shared/DataTable/TableRow.tsx:21:18)
    at tbody
    at table
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/Box/Box.js:45:18)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/Table/Table.js:57:87)
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/Box/Box.js:45:18)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/Stack/Stack.js:49:87)
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/Box/Box.js:45:18)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/Stack/Stack.js:49:87)
    at DataTable (webpack-internal:///./Components/shared/DataTable/DataTable.tsx:57:25)
    at Draws (webpack-internal:///./Components/draws/index.tsx:64:64)
    at ComponentName
    at main
    at div
    at div
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/Box/Box.js:45:18)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/core/esm/AppShell/AppShell.js:50:87)
    at AppComponent (webpack-internal:///./Components/AppComponents/AppComponent.tsx:19:37)
    at Home (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/dashboard.tsx:57:65)
    at AuthGuard (webpack-internal:///./Components/RouterGuard/auth-guard.tsx:49:23)
    at ThemeProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@emotion/react/dist/emotion-element-43c6fea0.browser.esm.js:123:50)
    at MantineProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mantine/styles/esm/theme/MantineProvider.js:78:3)
    at Provider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jotai/esm/react.mjs:23:3)
    at QueryClientProvider (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/react-query/es/react/QueryClientProvider.js:39:21)
    at App (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/_app.tsx:39:24)
    at PathnameContextProviderAdapter (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/shared/lib/router/adapters.js:107:25)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:303:63)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@next/react-dev-overlay/dist/client.js:852:919)
    at Container (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:149:5)
    at AppContainer (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:314:24)
    at Root (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/next/dist/client/index.js:532:25)

Below is the component's code and the package's package.json:
TextDisplay:
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TextProps, Stack, CSSObject } from '@mantine/core';
import { CSSProperties, useState } from 'react';
import Lottie from 'lottie-react';
import GreenCheckAnimation from '../resources/lottie/greenCheck.json';

interface TextDisplayProps extends TextProps {
  children: string | undefined;
  maxWidth?: string | number;
}

const defaultStyle = {
  position: 'relative',
  paddingInlineEnd: '40px',
  marginInlineEnd: '-40px',
  overflow: 'hidden',
  textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
} as CSSProperties;

const textContainerStyle = {
  width: '100%',
  height: 'calc(100% + 10px) !important',
  position: 'absolute',
  top: -5,
  left: -5,
  '&:hover > div > div': {
    opacity: 1,
  },
} as CSSObject;

const clipboardContainerStyle = {
  width: '24px',
  height: '24px',
  cursor: 'pointer',
  position: 'absolute',
  display: 'flex',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  right: 5,
  top: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  marginTop: 'auto',
  marginBottom: 'auto',
} as CSSObject;

const iconContainer = {
  opacity: 0,
  transition: 'opacity 0.1s ease',
} as CSSObject;

const TextDisplay = ({ maxWidth, ...props }: TextDisplayProps) => {
  const [copied, setCopied] = useState(false);

  /**
   * Copy the text to the clipboard and shows a green
   * check animation when the text is copied.
   */
  const copyToClipboard = async (e: any) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setCopied(true);

    if (props?.children) {
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText(props?.children);
    }

    setTimeout(() => setCopied(false), 2500);
  };

  return (
    <Text {...props} style={{ ...defaultStyle, ...props.style, maxWidth }}>
      {props.children}
      <ClipboardCopy copied={copied} copyToClipboard={copyToClipboard} />
    </Text>
  );
};

const ClipboardCopy = ({
  copied,
  copyToClipboard,
}: {
  copied: boolean;
  copyToClipboard: (e: any) => Promise<void>;
}) => {
  return (
    <Stack sx={textContainerStyle}>
      <Stack sx={clipboardContainerStyle}>
        {!copied && (
          <Stack sx={iconContainer} onClick={copyToClipboard}>
            <div>copy</div>
          </Stack>
        )}
        {copied && (
          <Lottie
            animationData={GreenCheckAnimation}
            loop={false}
            style={{ width: '30px', height: '30px' }}
          />
        )}
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
};

export default TextDisplay;

package.json:
{
  "name": "@mypackage/core",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Generic core UI components to be used across my sites",
  "main": "dist/esm/index.js",
  "types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
  "type": "module",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/esm/index.js",
      "types": "./dist/types/index.d.ts",
      "default": "./dist/esm/index.js"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "exit 0",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "author": "Me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lottie-react": "^2.4.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@mantine/core": "6.0.21",
    "@mantine/hooks": "6.0.21",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.15.3",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}


Any help would be much appreciated.
What did I try so far?
I tried logging out the Lottie component and the imported JSON. The logs showed that the JSON was imported correctly and the outputed Lottie seemed to be a valid JSX object.
I wanted to confirm that at that point it should be an object so I logged out a mantine Text component and it seemed to be of the same structure.
In addition I tried using the ts code from the package directly as I thought the issue might lie in trying to use the compiled esm code but that didn't seem to have any effect.
